# How to insert an array with some repeating values into mysql using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, forms

I'm trying to insert and values into my database and I thought having the same name for the inputs in my form would make it easier for me to insert them in bulk, I want to iterate OrderNo and quantity and insert them to a new column while keeping the other inputs such as fname the same until the values in OrderNo are done.

```
app.post("/send-data", (req,res)=>{
        let sql = "INSERT INTO foodorder.orders (" +
            "food_id," +
            " qty,"+ 
            " customer_FName," + 
            " customer_LName," +
            " customer_number," +
            " customer_email," +
            " customer_facebook," +
            " order_date," +
            " delivery_option," +
            " mode_of_payment," +
            " delivery_time" +
            ") VALUES (" + 
                ` ${req.body.OrderNo},` +
                ` ${req.body.quantity},` +
                ` "${req.body.fname}",` +
                ` "${req.body.lname}",` +
                ` "${req.body.Contact}",` +
                ` "${req.body.email}",` +
                ` "${req.body.facebook}",` + 
                ` "${req.body.date}",` + 
                ` "${req.body.delivery}",` +
                ` "${req.body.payment}",` +
                `"${req.body.time}"` +
                `)`;      
        con.query(sql, (err,result) => {
            if(!err){
                res.send(result);
            }
            else{
                res.json(req.body);
                throw err;
            }
        })
    });
```

This is the code that I have and currently it only accepts 1 OrderNo and quantity and when I try to order many products with different quantities it will say column count doesn't match
value count at row 1 (see attached photo below)

[the output i get from my forms *I didnt include in the screenshot the other output details such as email etc.][1]

is there a way to just iterate the OrderNo and quantity and insert them creating new columns but with the same fname and lname etc.? or do i need to use MySql cursor?

Note that my code works and inserts if i only have selected 1 order and 1 quantity in my forms

**UPDATE**

Attached here is what I wanna achieve. I wanna know a way to iterate or loop the OrderNo and quantity and insert them into their respective columns while keeping the other values the same like fname and lname.

[I wanna achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPyDH.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand you question (try to add some punctuation...) but it seems to me you're problem starts with how you are modelling the payload schema. Also your database schema is probably not optimal for this situation. Maybe consider a table for orders and another for items?

Comment: Also very important, don't interpolate the payload values into the query string. This is vulnerable to SQL injection. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values

Comment: @DiogoSimões thanks about the concern on SQL injection but I'm currently not worried about it because I'm only using it for a project and might not actually implement it. as per the question ill send a photo on what I want to achieve with the given output

Comment: You just need to iterate OrderNo and for each element you make an insert statement (or add values to the insert statement).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by iterating the OrderNo. Thanks so much Diogo

```
app.post("/send-data", (req,res)=>{
        let order = req.body.OrderNo;
        let quantity = req.body.quantity;
        let first = req.body.fname, 
        last = req.body.lname,
        contact = req.body.Contact,
        email = req.body.emailAdd,
        fb = req.body.facebook,
        date = req.body.date,
        delivery = req.body.delivery,
        payment = req.body.payment,
        time = req.body.time,
        address = req.body.address;
        [order].forEach((product, index, arr)=>{
                const q = quantity[index];
                let sql = "INSERT INTO foodorder.orders (" +
                    "food_id," +
                    " qty,"+ 
                    " customer_FName," + 
                    " customer_LName," +
                    " customer_address," +
                    " customer_number," +
                    " customer_email," +
                    " customer_facebook," +
                    " order_date," +
                    " delivery_option," +
                    " mode_of_payment," +
                    " delivery_time" +
                 ") VALUES (" + 
                     con.escape(product) + `,` +
                     con.escape(q) + `,` +
                     con.escape(first) + `,` +
                     con.escape(last) + `,` +
                     con.escape(address) + `,` +
                     con.escape(contact) + `,` +
                     con.escape(""+email) + `,` +
                     con.escape(fb) + `,` +
                     con.escape(date) + `,` +
                     con.escape(delivery) + `,` +
                     con.escape(payment) + `,` +
                     con.escape(time) +
                     `)`; 
                con.query(sql, (err,result) => {
                    if(!err){
                        res.redirect('thankyou.html');
                    }
                    else{
                        res.status(404).send('ERROR. Please Go back and Order Again');
                    }
                })
        })
    });
```